# pthread_cond_wait() and signal, the result depend on OS

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, macos, solaris

I am a beginner of multi-threaded programming, and now I know that when a signal was sent while waiting with `pthead_cond_wait()`, the result depends on the OS.
Can somebody tell me how to know how the call was interrupted, and how to write portable code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void
sigusr1_handler(int sig)
{
    printf("signal called\n");
}

int
main()
{
    int n;
    pthread_mutex_t mut;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    struct timespec ts;

    signal(SIGUSR1, sigusr1_handler);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mut, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    printf("before cond_wait\n");
    n = pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mut);
    printf("after pthread_cond_wait : %d\n", n);
    perror("error pthread_cond_wait:");

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
MacOS X 10.11.4
cc -o condwait condwait.c -lpthread

Linux 2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64
gcc -o condwait condwait.c -lpthread

Solaris11 5.11 11.2
cc -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -mt -o condwait condwait.c -lpthread

MacOS X
$ ./condwait &
[1] xxxxx
$ kill -USR1 %1
signal called
after pthread_cond_wait : 0
error pthread_cond_wait:: Unknown error: 260

Solaris
$ ./condwait &
[1] xxxxx
$ kill -USR1 %1
signal called
after pthread_cond_wait : 0
error pthread_cond_wait : Error 0

Linux
$ ./condwait &
[1] xxxxx
$ kill -USR1 %1
signal called
$ jobs
[1]+  Running
```

When using Solaris native `cond_wait()`, it returns `EINTR` as documented.
Is there any idea how to know that `pthread_cond_wait()` was interrupted?

Answer (score 2):

POSIX specifies that this function will never return EINTR. For portability to legacy OSes you can check for it anyway, it doesn't hurt

More importantly, you should be prepared for spurious wakeups. The function can return zero at any time for any reason wiith the condition not being met. The mutex will be locked. You have to check the condition and, if not met, go back to pthread_cond_wait.

Comment: Dear n.m. Thank you for your answer. Maybe you want to tell me like [    pthread_mutex_lock();
        while(condition_is_false)
            pthread_cond_wait();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(); ]

Comment: Yes this is the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I read the Linux `pthread_cond_wait`'s man manual, it says:

> If a signal is delivered to a thread waiting for a condition variable, upon return from the signal handler the thread resumes  waiting  for  the condition variable as if it was not interrupted, or it shall return zero due to spurious wakeup.

I  guess other OS's also have manuals to help you figure it out.

Comment: Dear barcelona_delpy, thank you for your answer.  I read japanese version manual of Linux, and it says pthread_cond_timedwait returns EINTR when signaled. I'd look for some manuals, only SUS3 manual tells returns error. Then I have to block signals while waiting condition on MacOS X and Solaris, SUS3. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for everyone.
Now I know that with using signal to stop long waiting condition do not work.
pthread_cond_wait() resume waiting for the condition as if it was not interrupted, or it returns zero due to spurious wakeup.
Then I want to do that, I will need a second lock like

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
while(condition_is_false) {
  n = pthread_cond_timedwait();
  if (n == ETIMEDOUT) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut2);
    if (condition2_is_true) {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut2);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
      return STOPPED;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut2);
  }
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
return 0;
```

Regards,