# How to wake the sleeping threads and exit the main thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am creating 10 threads. Each thread will do some task. There are 7 tasks to be done. Since number of tasks are less than the number of threads, there would always be 3 threads that sleep and do nothing.

My main thread must wait for the tasks to get completed and exit only when all the tasks are done (i.e when the thread exits). I am waiting in a for loop and calling `pthread_join` but with the 3 threads that are sleeping, how can I wake them up and make them exit?

Here is what I am doing now.

```
// thread handler function, called when the thread is created
void* handler_func(void* arg) {
  while(true){
       pthread_mutex_lock(&my_queue_mutex);
           while(my_queue_is_empty()) {
                 pthread_cond_wait(&my_cond_var, &my_queue_mutex);
           }
           item = get_item_from_queue();
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_queue_mutex);
   }   
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int total_threads_to_create = 10;
int total_requests_to_make = 7;
pthread_t threads[total_threads_to_create];


for(int i = 0; i < total_threads_to_create; i++) {
     // create threads
     pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, handler_func, NULL);

}

for(int i=0;i<total_requests_to_make;i++){
      // fill up the task queue
      add_task_to_my_queue(i + 100);

}



for(int i = 0; i< total_threads_to_create; i++) {
       // wait for threads to finish
       pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the simplest solution in this case would be to create **7** threads.  Each time you need to perform a task, create a new thread to perform it.  I don't see much use in creating a thread that doesn't have anything to do ... why bother?

Comment: @MikeRobinson Yes, but the parameter `7` is beyond my control

Comment: Another way to do it is to send a signal.  For instance, `SIGUSR1`.  This would be a notification from the parent that the program is stopping.  Idle threads would catch the signal and terminate themselves.  Busy threads would ignore it ... or, they could also use the signal as an indication that they should "wrap up early."  Signals are handy because they're asynchronous:  threads and processes don't have to look for them, just catch them when and if they arrive.

Comment: (Although the API routine is ominously called `pthread_kill`, it actually "sends a signal of your choice.")

Comment: @MikeRobinson, those idle threads are inside a `pthread_cond_wait` call, which [doesn't return EINTR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39242713/132382) and for practical purposes is not interruptible by a signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to enqueue dummy tasks that indicate "all done" to the workers, since you know the number of workers in advance:

```
for(int i=0;i<total_threads_to_create;i++){
  // a task of -1 means "no more work"
  add_task_to_my_queue(-1);
}
```

Alternatively, you can have a "breakable" queue.   This queue wakes up waiting consumers with a compound predicate:  either non-empty *or* finished.  Perl's Thread::Queue objects can be [ended](https://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Queue.html#-%3eend()), for example, and Python's queues can track [completed tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.task_done).

Another option would be to keep track of the number of tasks completed yourself, with its own condition variable and mutex or a "countdown latch" or whatever, and not care about the worker threads.  They'll be vaporized when the program exits.

Comment: I've used a `NULL` pointer to indicate "No more work" when the queue consists of pointers to various task structures.  Dump an appropriate number of `NULL` values into the queue and then wait for all the worker threads to exist.

Comment: @AndrewHenle if the work threads post the NULL back to the queue before terminating, you only need to post one NULL, irrespective of how many threads are waiting:)