# Noticing if all threads are at pthread_cond_wait

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I'm currently playing around with the POSIX library and trying out conditional variables.
At the moment I'm using a queue to scheduele tasks, if there is a task one thread uses pthread_cond_signal to wake up a thread that is waiting at pthread_cond_wait.
However there might be a point where no new tasks are created, so every thread is waiting at pthread_cond_wait and the programm is stuck there.

Is there anyway for me noticing if all my threads are waiting at pthread_cond_wait? I've tried using a counter and a leave variable but I did not get it working.

My code looks simliar to this code here: https://code-vault.net/lesson/j62v2novkv:1609958966824
,except each thread is adding new tasks (in executeTask) instead of only the main method adding them.

EDIT:
Here is my version of the code from the website above (which is loading for me:/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#define THREAD_NUM 4

typedef struct Task
{
    int a, b;
} Task;

Task taskQueue[256];
int taskCount = 0;
// THIS VARIABLE IS ADDED
int moreTasks = 10;

pthread_mutex_t mutexQueue;
pthread_cond_t condQueue;

void executeTask(Task *task)
{
    usleep(50000);
    int result = task->a + task->b;
    printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d\n", task->a, task->b, result);

    // THIS PART IS ADDED 
    if (moreTasks > 0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexQueue);
        moreTasks--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexQueue);
        Task t = {
            .a = rand() % 100,
            .b = rand() % 100};
        submitTask(t);
    }
}

void submitTask(Task task)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexQueue);
    taskQueue[taskCount] = task;
    taskCount++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexQueue);
    pthread_cond_signal(&condQueue);
}

void *startThread(void *args)
{
    while (1)
    {
        Task task;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexQueue);
        while (taskCount == 0)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&condQueue, &mutexQueue);
        }

        task = taskQueue[0];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < taskCount - 1; i++)
        {
            taskQueue[i] = taskQueue[i + 1];
        }
        taskCount--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexQueue);
        executeTask(&task);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t th[THREAD_NUM];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexQueue, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&condQueue, NULL);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &startThread, NULL) != 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to create the thread");
        }
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Task t = {
            .a = rand() % 100,
            .b = rand() % 100};
        submitTask(t);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++)
    {
        if (pthread_join(th[i], NULL) != 0)
        {
            perror("Failed to join the thread");
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexQueue);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&condQueue);
    return 0;
}
```

My Probleme now is that after a while the taskCount is always zero and tehrefore all my threads are at  `pthread_cond_wait(&condQueue, &mutexQueue);` in the `startThread` methods.
Is ther any way of me noticing if all threads are at this place? As statet above if already tried using a counter for the threads that are currently waiting (and also a version where I counted the threads that are working) but I could not figure out how to stop all the threads once every task is done.

Comment: That link leads to a blank page, and code links are discouraged anyway. Your post should include a proper [mcve] that *we* can use/examine to reproduce *your* problem. This doesn't sound like a "is everyone waiting" scenario; this sounds like the code posting to the queue is doing something wrong. When no data is in the queue by-definition every thread should eventually reach idle. I'm not sure I understand the usefulness or goal you're trying to accomplish by knowing that has happened, short of thinking of some exit strategy, which should be part of the predicate state anyway; not concocted.

Comment: @WhozCraig Hey, thanks for your answer. Weird that the site is not loading for you. If put the code into my question now and also tried to eleborate my problem. English is not my native tongue so it is kinda hard to put my problem into words, sorry for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wake the sleeping threads and exit the main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079767/how-to-wake-the-sleeping-threads-and-exit-the-main-thread)  That question asks, how do I notify queue consumers that the queue is permanently empty?

Comment: Two errors:  Reading `moreTasks` without locking its associated mutex is incorrect.  Also, `perror` after `pthread_create` is inappropriate and misleading — the latter doesn't set `errno`.  Two suggestions to pare down the code: use static mutex/cond initialization, and fold your `rand() % 100` into a `makeNewTask` (or perhaps just a `makeAndSubmitTask`) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know how many threads are waiting on a condition var, just increase a global counter before you go into wait mode and decrease it on wake up. With that you'll know how many threads are currently waiting.

e.g.

```
//global scope
int num_waiting_threads = 0;

//in function startThread
while (taskCount == 0)
{
    //if num_waiting_threads == THREAD_NUM, all threads are waiting
    ++num_waiting_threads;
    pthread_cond_wait(&condQueue, &mutexQueue);
    --num_waiting_threads;
}
```

Since you have a fixed number of tasks, after processing every task, every thread will be sooner or later just waiting around for newly submitted tasks. Your execute function will only add in total 10 new tasks (`moreTasks` is initialized with 10 and decreased continuously and if that counter hits zero, no more tasks will be submitted).

Therefore, you could/should use `pthread_cond_timedwait` and wake up by yourself to check the `num_waiting_threads` state. If all threads are waiting, break out of the loop and exit the thread.